# Get access to prototype context when adding a function

Tags: javascript, this, prototype, extend

I would like to add a function to a prototype to add a feature to a library.
How can I access to the "this" context of the prototype?
I give you an example to explain what I mean.

```js
// file a

import * as utils from './utils'
import Validation from './b'

Validation.prototype.unique = function(url, params) {
  if (!utils.isEmptyString(url) && !utils.isEmptyObject(params) {
    // make api call for testing if unique
    this._messages.push('Unique'); // <= I would like to access to "this" context of Validation in file b.
  }
  return this;
}



// file b
import * as utils from './utils'

export function Validation() {
  this._messages = [];
  this._value = undefined;
  //...
}

Validation.prototype.required = function() {
  if (!utils.isEmpty(this._value)) {
    this._messages.push('Required);
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: That just works; it doesn't matter at all which file your function happens to be defined in.  `this` is just passed by the callsite.

Comment: Side note: You'll see some people using the term "context" to refer to the value of `this`, but "context" (as defined by the spec) and `this` have very little to do with one-another. `this` is just `this`. :-)

Comment: If `Validation.prototype.unique` is called "correctly", namely has method of a `Validation` instance, then `this` will just refer to that instance. *"I would like to access to "this" context of file b"* I don't think that's whats you want ;)

Comment: When you try to use `this` at the point in the code you marked, does it not work for you? You haven't mentioned anything not working for you. What is the issue you experience? Until you tried something this seems to be just a hypothetical question which most likely results in discussions around should or it should not work.

Comment: While you can do it that way, you run into the possibility of clobbering other extensions to `Validation` with the same name. This is an issue with any library code or the built-in stuff. You could subclass instead. `class MyValidation extends Validation { unique(url, params) {...} }`

Comment: It works indeed. My question is based on something concrete that I want to do but the code I put was an example for you to understand the idea.  Felix King, yes I was talking about Validation instance on file b. ;)
Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `this` in the method works exactly like that. The only thing that needs to be fixed are the non-matching import and export statements. Either use

```
// file a
import Validation from './b'
…
```

```
// file b
export default function Validation() {…}
```

or

```
// file a
import { Validation } from './b'
…
```

```
// file b
export function Validation() {…}
```

Comment: Yes you are right, I wrote this code in browser and I made mistake. The flexibility of Javascript is nice.